# How to bypass middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to bypass one of the middleware using next('route'). Even then the control is passed to next middleware instead of passing it to route path.

```
fun1 = (req,res,next) =>{
    res.locals.isLogin = true;
    next('route');
}

fun2 = (req,res,next) =>{
    res.locals.isLogin1 = true;
    next();
}

app.use(fun1);
app.use(fun2);

app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.write('<h1>Hello ' + res.locals.isLogin + ' and ' + res.locals.isLogin1);
    res.end();
});
```

[image: Response]

Comment: And using `res.redirect('/')` does not satisfy the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `next('route')` facility doesn't skip middleware added through the `use()` function, see: [Using middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

> **Documentation :** To skip the rest of the middleware functions from a router middleware
>   stack, call `next('route')` to pass control to the next route. NOTE:
>   `next('route')` will work only in middleware functions that were loaded
>   by using the app.METHOD() or router.METHOD() functions.

So, To skip `fun2` here are the changes on your code,

```
fun1 = (req,res,next) =>{
    res.locals.isLogin = true;
    next('route');
}

fun2 = (req,res,next) =>{
    res.locals.isLogin1 = true;
    next();
}

app.get('/', fun1, fun2);

app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.write('<h1>Hello ' + res.locals.isLogin + ' and ' + res.locals.isLogin1);
    res.end();
});
```